# Manipulating dom elements in componentDidMount only working with a timeout

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, queryselector

I am working on a react widget where I render some elements to the screen. Initially I do not yet know what the actual widths of some of the elements are, as they are dependent on the offsetWidths of other elements.

Therefore, I am initially giving these elements a default width and then I am changing the width after the component mounts by using queryselectors.

Funny thing: I need wrap this in a setTimeout using a timeout of say 100 ms for this to work (edit: sometimes 100 ms is not even enough!).

So, this works:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.styleWidget();
    }, 100);    //Sometimes 100ms is not even enough!
}
```

And this does not work:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    this.styleWidget();
}
```

Anyone know why I need the timeout and how to prevent the use of this timeout, because it's smells...

By the way, my styleWidget method is just getting the offsetWidth of the widget itself and then sets the width of the elements within the widget based on this offsetWidth.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a smell. Do you basically just need to wait until a second render cycle to call `styleWidget`?

Comment: Good question. So what is the solution? How to prevent this! Documentation suggests that it should work without the timeout. I mean, componentDidMount is running if everything is there, right?

Comment: Ideally. Can you share a more comprehensive component code example for us to inspect?